# Transaction not working after unsuccessful connection to redis using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm not sure, whether it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code:

```
        using StackExchange.Redis;

        ConnectionMultiplexer conn = null;
        while (conn == null);
        {
            try
            {
                conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                conn = null;
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }

        var db = conn.GetDatabase();
        var transaction = db.CreateTransaction();

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(transaction.HashSetAsync("key", "field", "value"));
        if (transaction.Execute())
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
```

When I run it with started redis (windows version - 2.6, 2.8.17, 2.8.19), everything works fine. If I start redis after few loops of the cycle, either it doesn't jump into if-statement or it jumps and get blocked on WaitAll(). If I try to check values in redis, they are stored.

This situation happens when we start server and forget to start redis. After postpone start of redis it gets stuck. The same problem appears when using batch instead of transaction.

Am I doing connection to multiplexer wrong or is it bug? (I found few that looked similar but I'm not sure)

Comment: That suggests the tasks are not being marked completed in some code path - I will have to investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in older versions of StackExchange.Redis - 1.0.481, 1.0.488 (didn't test any older ones). With new version 1.1.553 it works fine (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/200).